# Can expired cat shampoo still be use?

Tags: cats, grooming, bathing

I am using this BioGance cat shampoo for my cat. However since I did not need to bathe my cat that frequently (usually once every 2-3 months depending if she needs a bath), I found that the shampoo to be expired on Sept 2014.

Should I continue using it? Will there be any side effects (harmful)?

This is the shampoo I am using:

[image: BioGance Cat Shampoo]

Comment: I don't know specifically about cat shampoo, but for most medicine or hygiene products, the expiration date simply indicates that span of time when the product will be most effective.  So I think it is likely it will not harm the cat, but it also might not work as well.

Comment: @Kai Oic.. Thank you for your explaination I think I should go buy a new bottle of it.